Klarna SignIn(iOS) event handler doesn't intercept events
I'm trying to implement a native module for Klarna signin for iOs in my expo app.
I have already implemented 'klarnaSignIn' function which opens Klarna signin view. I press submit after filling some user info in this view, but the KlarnaEventHandler doesn't intercept signin events - I don't see "Event"/"Error" in the console.
I'm a newbie in swift and appreciate if you show me the right direction.
This is my ExpoKlarnaAuthModule.swift:
import Foundation
import ExpoModulesCore
import AuthenticationServices
import KlarnaMobileSDK

public class ExpoKlarnaAuthModule: Module {
    var signInResult: String?
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    
    public func definition() -> ModuleDefinition {
        Name("ExpoKlarnaAuth")
        
        Function("klarnaSignIn") { (
            returnUrl: String,
            clientId: String,
            scope: String,
            market: String,
            klarnaEnv: String,
            region: String?
        ) -> String in
            self.startKlarnaSignIn(
                returnUrl: returnUrl,
                clientId: clientId,
                scope: scope,
                market: market,
                klarnaEnv: klarnaEnv,
                region: region
            )
        }

        View(ExpoKlarnaAuthView.self) {}
    }
    
    func startKlarnaSignIn(
        returnUrl: String,
        clientId: String,
        scope: String,
        market: String,
        klarnaEnv: String,
        region: String? = nil
    ) -> String {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let returnUrl = URL(string: returnUrl) else { return }
            
            let klarnaSignInSDK = KlarnaSignInSDK(
                theme: KlarnaTheme.automatic,
                environment: KlarnaMobileSDK.KlarnaEnvironment.playground,
                region: KlarnaMobileSDK.KlarnaRegion.eu,
                resourceEndpoint: KlarnaResourceEndpoint.alternative1,
                returnUrl: returnUrl,
                eventHandler: self,
                loggingLevel: KlarnaLoggingLevel.verbose
            )
            
            let signInButtonView = ExpoKlarnaAuthView()
            
            klarnaSignInSDK.signIn(clientId: clientId, scope: scope, market: market, locale: "SV", tokenizationId: nil, presentationContext: signInButtonView)
        }
        
        let timeoutResult = dispatchGroup.wait(timeout: .now() + 10)
        
        if timeoutResult == .timedOut {
            return "Error: Sign-in process timed out"
        }

        return signInResult ?? "Error: Sign-in did not complete"
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ExpoKlarnaAuthModule: KlarnaEventHandler {
    public func klarnaComponent(_ klarnaComponent: KlarnaComponent, dispatchedEvent event: KlarnaProductEvent) {
        print("Event")
        
        signInResult = "event"
        
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    public func klarnaComponent(_ klarnaComponent: KlarnaComponent, encounteredError error: KlarnaError) {
        print("Error")
        
        signInResult = "error"

        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

This is my ExpoKlarnaAuthView.swift:
import ExpoModulesCore
import AuthenticationServices

class ExpoKlarnaAuthView: ExpoView, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else {
            print("No Window")
            fatalError("Window is not set")
        }
        
        return window
    }
}


